# Grouped NSTableView in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nstableview

I am using coreData for displaying the data in the tableView.The model is  Investment where I have attributes like name(String), amount(Number), completed(Bool). Now, I wanted to group the tableView based on the Name or Completed attribute. I know I have to use `tableView:isGroupRow:` delegate Method.But I am not getting how to use it to display it in the table view.Any Lead would be appreciated.

Comment: Completed can be grouped completed / not completed, but how do you want to group the names? Alphabetically for each letter? Unlike iOS `NSTableView` has no sections. All table view cells including the group rows are inline and need a distinct attribute to be distinguished.

Comment: Yeah in case of names alphabetically

Comment: I want to know how can i group for both names and completed and

Comment: In any case you have to compose the data source array programmatically by adding the group rows and the data rows respectively and treat them accordingly in `viewForTableColumn` and `isGroupRow`. In case of  completed add the completed group row, fetch the completed data from Core Data, add the uncompleted group row and fetch the uncompleted data and reload the table view. PS: An `NSOutlineView` might be more suitable...

Comment: I am using arrayController. Correct me if I am wrong. Are you telling that I should count the number of objects from the tableview and insert a string into it. And in case of completed i should check how many investment are completed then O should add a string in between those objects.

Comment: Yes, once again all table view cells are inline, there are no sections or other nested collection objects. You could use a backing nested array but you have to flatten it when the items are displayed.